# Best performance: Gnome 3, Unity or Cinnamon?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments, cinnamon

Which one of these three configurations consumes the least resources?

Comment: Not familiar with Cinnamon, but Gnome 3 seems slightly more stable and less resource intensive than Unity, in 11.10

Comment: This is not the kind of question that is appropriate for this site. It would lead to loads of opinion :(.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is ontopic here, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is based off of GNOME, and uses more RAM. Cinnamon is a little less resource hungry, but if you are looking for a desktop environment when resources is a factor, you might want to give LXDE a try. It's a fairly pretty desktop environment that runs in 128 megabytes of RAM. It has an interface very similar interface to KDE with less eye candy.

Comment: Actually, I beg to differ - 12.04 seems very, very slick with the open source ATI drivers, which is unheard of.

Comment: YEs, they did a good job on Unity. But, LXDE is faster.

Comment: I have had the same issue with Unity being heavy on my laptop. I have 16meg of Ram and a high end Quad core, but it is laggy at times. Tried XFCE, really good, but feels incomplete as an OS at the moment. Why did they close this? the rules here are strange!